# Appcelerator Studio - Specify different path for build and Resources folder

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

Is it possible to configure an alternate path for the /build and Resources folder for an Alloy project?

I cannot find an option to customize the build/run configuration in Appcelerator Studio Preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.

Alloy is a plugin for the Titanium CLI and it will read from `app` and compile/transpile to `Resources`. Titanium then will read from `Resources` and compile/build to `build`. This is not configurable.